# Android facebook login callback not happening

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to implement Facebook login for my android app using the facebook sdk 4.1.0. The LoginButton is placed inside a splashActivity and upon successful login should start the MainActivity. However, the facebook callback method is not runnning at all for me and I can't figure out what is causing this.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(this.getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    cache = new DiskBasedCache(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir(), 1024 * 1024);
    network = new BasicNetwork(new HurlStack());
    mRequestQueue =  new RequestQueue(cache, network);
    getUserInfo();

    skip = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSkip);
    skip.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent done = new Intent(getBaseContext(),MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(done);
            finish();
        }
    });

    loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Call private method
            onFblogin();
            loginButton.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    loginButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    });

    accessTokenTracker = new AccessTokenTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentAccessTokenChanged(AccessToken oldAccessToken, AccessToken newAccessToken) {
            if(newAccessToken == null){
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();
            }

        }
    };
    AccessToken accessToken = AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken();
    if(accessToken != null){
        skip.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        Intent done = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(done);
        finish();
    }
    ProfileTracker profileTracker = new ProfileTracker() {
        @Override
        protected void onCurrentProfileChanged(Profile oldProfile, Profile newProfile) {

        }
    };


    accessTokenTracker.startTracking();
}






private void onFblogin() {
        // Set permissions
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this,  Arrays.asList("email", "public_profile"));
        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(callbackManager,
                new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                        AccessToken token = loginResult.getAccessToken();
//                        Set denied = loginResult.getRecentlyDeniedPermissions();
//                        loginResult.getRecentlyGrantedPermissions();
                        System.out.println("Success");
                        GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
                                loginResult.getAccessToken(), new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onCompleted(JSONObject jsonObject, GraphResponse graphResponse) {
                                        if (graphResponse.getError() != null) {
                                            // handle error
                                            System.out.println("ERROR");
                                        } else {
                                            try {
                                                mRequestQueue.start();
                                                String jsonresult = String.valueOf(jsonObject);
                                                System.out.println("JSON Result" + jsonresult);

                                                JSONObject loginDetailsJSON = new JSONObject();
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("id", jsonObject.getString("id"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("name", jsonObject.getString("name"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("first_name", jsonObject.getString("first_name"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("last_name", jsonObject.getString("last_name"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("link", jsonObject.getString("link"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("gender", jsonObject.getString("gender"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("locale", jsonObject.getString("locale"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("timezone", jsonObject.getString("timezone"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("email", jsonObject.getString("email"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("verified", jsonObject.getString("verified"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("updated_time", jsonObject.getString("updated_time"));
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("age_range", "");
                                                loginDetailsJSON.put("connector", "FB");
                                                JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                                                        connetionStrings.LoginUrl, loginDetailsJSON.toString(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                                                        try {
                                                            VolleyLog.v("Response:%n %s", response.toString(4));
                                                            Log.d("response: ", response.toString(4));
                                                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                            e.printStackTrace();
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                                        VolleyLog.e("Error: ", error.getMessage());

                                                        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please try again", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                                                        toast.show();
                                                    }

                                                });
                                                mRequestQueue.add(req);
                                                Intent done = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                                                startActivity(done);

                                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }).executeAsync();

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        Log.d("TAG_CANCEL", "On cancel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException error) {
                        Log.d("TAG_ERROR", error.toString());
                    }
                });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/v2.3#get_current and check, if you implemented everything (what I'm missing in your code is onActivityResult callback).
Don't put initation of callback into onFbLogin method - put it directly in onCreate. You don't have to add listener to LoginButton. It works just after inflation. And visibility of UI elements you can change in callback methods of FacebookCallback listener (make your activity implementation of it).

Comment: I have the onActivityResult() method in place already. Now here's the thing, when I debug the app, callback works just fine and so does the async call in the onSuccess method (perhaps due to the delay in processing that is brought about by the debugging). However, if i simply run the project, the same doesn't happen. Nothing inside the onSuccess of callback runs. Got any ideas for this?